# User's display name and email are missing in Outlook OfficeJS userProfile API

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

OfficeJS provides an API to access the logged in user's [profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.5/office.context.mailbox.userprofile). 
For example, if we need to get the email address of a particular user, we use the following code.

> Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress

We have ran into a weird issue with this API where it doesn't return a user's displayName and emailAddress for a few of our customers. 
The system where this issue was reproduced is on the latest Outlook version (v16.33).

Here's a screenshot of the console logs for your reference:

[image]

Is this a bug?

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, We are trying to reproduce this issue, could you tell us if the account this issue is showing up on is on Exchange online or is it on-premise or Gmail? Also, I assume you're able to see this only on Outlook for Mac, or on all clients (Windows, web, mobile)?

Comment: This is an on premise Exchange 2016 server and the issue seems to be only present on Mac

Comment: Could you tell us the Exchange build version?

Comment: We are trying to repro this issue on our end, is it possible for you to provide a test account?

Comment: Can we contact Juan with the details?

Comment: Yes, you can share the test account details with him.

Comment: Hello @SameeraJayaseckara, have you shared the details with Juan Balmori?

Comment: Could you please provide test account details to Juan Balmori so that we can investigate this more?

Comment: We haven't received an account from the customer who was experiencing this issue. We will post here once we get it.